# Not all the variables are been displayed in the bar plot in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, bar-chart, missing-data

I'm trying to introduce a variable for missing values as 1, and one having values in the original data set as 0. To see the effect the missing values causes in house prediction.

I upload my data set. I'm following a tutorial
Then I write the code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

house_data=pd.read_csv("/home/udemy/houseprice.csv")

#we evaluate the price of a house for those cases where the information is missing, for each variable
def analyse_na_value(df, var):
    # we indicate as a variable as 1 where the observation is missing
    # we indicate as 0 where the observation has a real value
    df[var] = np.where(df[var].isnull(), 1 , 0)
    #print(df[var].isnull())
    
    # we calculate the mean saleprice where the information is missing or present
    df.groupby(var)['SalePrice'].median().plot.bar()
    plt.title(var)
    plt.show()
    
    
for var in vars_with_na:
    analyse_na_value(house_data, var)
```

In the tutorial I'm following, the plot obtained both columns: those with the missing values contained the sale price of a house, and the sale price of a house with the missing values omitted.

However, in my jupyter notebook I only get the plot with missing values omitted as shown in image, while in tutorial there are 2 columns. I'm wondering what I did wrong.

[image]